# while running a docker image on container getting restart.sh file is not found

Tags: docker, dockerfile

when i am running the container getting restart.sh file is not found error

code in dockerFile:

```
  RUN addgroup --system ${USER_GROUP} && adduser --system 
  ${NON_ROOT_USER} --ingroup ${USER_GROUP}
  RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y netcat jq iputils-ping wget 
  vim curl
  COPY get-tca.sh /opt/tca/get-tca.sh
  COPY restart.sh /opt/tca/restart.sh
  RUN chmod 755 /opt/tca/restart.sh
  RUN chmod 755 /opt/tca/mr-watchdog.sh


  USER ${NON_ROOT_USER}:${USER_GROUP}

  ENTRYPOINT /opt/tca/restart.sh
```

Comment: So if /opt/tca/restart.sh is not found, then the files it not copied to container. are you sure that restart.sh is in the same directory that you Dockerfile is?

Comment: Also can happen if the interpreter named in the `#!` line at the start of the script isn't there, or (if it's a binary and not a script) if a shared-library dependency is missing.

Comment: yes it is in the same directory @golobich

Comment: can you please provided content of this restart file?

Comment: hey @golobich  thanks for u r contribution issue is solved with this http://sql313.com/index.php/43-main-blogs/maincat-dba/62-using-notepad-to-change-end-of-line-characters

Comment: thnaks @DavidMaze